# Array list wont display in my listview Android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

Please someone help me how to show all list array in listview, i have "eventname" which values are: "Party", "Study", "Exam".
and inside my for loop i have this codes and it only outputs "Exam"..

```
 lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                    List<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    your_array_list.add(eventname);

                    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CalendarActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            your_array_list );

                    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: add one by one values in your `your_array_list`

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding data in your arraylist correctly..you are adding only one data in arraylist.
 String[] array ={"EXAM","Study"};

```
    for(String str: array){
        your_array_list.add(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works properly, you are adding just one item:

```
your_array_list.add(eventname);
```

If you want to add the items "Party", "Study", "Exam", you should add them one by one:

```
your_array_list.add("Party");
your_array_list.add("Study");
your_array_list.add("Exam");
```

Or much better, declare them in a constant array and add them in a loop:

```
String[] ITEMS = new String[]{"Party", "Study", "Exam"};

...

for(String item : ITEMS) {
    your_array_list.add(item);
}
```

Also, consider using an enum instead of a constant array. But it depends on what you are specifically programming, of course.